# How to navigate to Location Services setting in an app

Tags: iphone, ios

When a user whose location services are off, goes to a page that needs Location, a UIAlertView would appear, and at the bottom, there is a button named "Setting". When "setting" is clicked, it would jump to System Setting - Location Service.

What's the button action, or the URI for navigating to Location Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS doesn't provide an explicit way or URL to navigate to the Settings page.

As far as Location services are concerned, whenever an app tries to use location services, if the "Location Services" in the settings page is set to NO, iOS prompts an alertView for the user to enable (set YES) the option. On subsequent launches, if this option is set to YES, the user will not get this alertView.

Comment: I found they only appeare once

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to [modify your `Info.plist` file to include `location-services`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) in your `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` entry

Comment: it could not give out a Button named "setting"

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];
```

You can do the above, but I don't know  whether the App will pass through Apple's app review.If you know, please tell me.

Reference: [jump to setting interface in iOS](http://www.jianshu.com/p/6de8b464d7f2).

Answer (score 0):

This will lead you to app setting page..Were you can change the Setting for you application including Location service..

```
 NSURL *appSettings = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appSettings];
```